# How to show favicon in subdomain xml file

Tags: favicon

I have a subdomain `feeds.domain.com`, The root Directory for this subdomain is in main domain(`/public_html/feeds/`), I

I have placed favicon in root(`/public_html/`) and subdomain root(`/public_html/feeds/`) directory.

Now favicon is not displayed in browser for xml files that are in subdomain, xml files in other directory are showing favicon though.

Why browser is not picking favicon for xml from subdomain.

Example url where favicon not showing is `feeds.domain.com/all/index.xml`

Example url where favicon showing is `www.domain.com/feeds/all/index.xml`, (this is sub domain directory showing favicon when accessed directly from domain)

If I enter url `feeds.domain.com/favicon.ico` browser displays favicon.

Please see and suggest any possible way to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it solved, I deleted all browser history and cleared browser cache now it is showing favicon, I hope this helps others too with same issue.

Thanks.